# Create new observations in SAS based on existing variables

Tags: sas

I want to create 1 new observation based on the KEY variable. For each set of observations with identical KEY variables, create new variable MASTER, where MASTER=1 for the new observation. Also, for each set of observations with identical KEY variable, if AGE, LOCATION, TYPE are an exact match, copy that data to the new observation. If not an exact match, leave blank.

What I have:

| KEY | AGE | LOCATION | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 22 | XX | NEW |
| 1001 | 22 | YY | NEW |
| 1006 | 30 | AA | OLD |
| 1006 | 31 | AA | OLD |
| 1006 | 30 | AA | OLD |

What I want:

| KEY | AGE | LOCATION | TYPE | MASTER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 22 | XX | NEW |  |
| 1001 | 22 | YY | NEW |  |
| 1001 | 22 |  | NEW | 1 |
| 1006 | 30 | AA | OLD |  |
| 1006 | 31 | AA | OLD |  |
| 1006 | 30 | AA | OLD |  |
| 1006 |  | AA | OLD | 1 |

Comment: Please show the code you have tried.  Are you familiar with by-group processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So set the dataset by KEY and use FIRST./LAST. flags.  To check if any of the other variables change you can use lagged values.

First let's convert your listing into an actual SAS dataset.

```
data have;
  input KEY AGE LOCATION $ TYPE $;
cards;
1001 22 XX NEW
1001 22 YY NEW
1006 30 AA OLD
1006 31 AA OLD
1006 30 AA OLD
;
```

We can create some retained variables to keep track of whether there has been a change.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by key ;
  retain many_age many_location many_type;
  lag_age=lag(age);
  lag_location=lag(location);
  lag_type=lag(type);
  if first.key then call missing(of many_:);
  else do;
    many_age+(age ne lag_age);
    many_location+(location ne lag_location);
    many_type+(type ne lag_type);
  end;
  output;
  if last.key then do;
    master=1;
    if many_age then call missing(age);
    if many_location then call missing(location);
    if many_type then call missing(type);
    output;
  end;
  drop lag_: many_: ;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs     KEY    AGE    LOCATION    TYPE    master

 1     1001     22       XX       NEW        .
 2     1001     22       YY       NEW        .
 3     1001     22                NEW        1
 4     1006     30       AA       OLD        .
 5     1006     31       AA       OLD        .
 6     1006     30       AA       OLD        .
 7     1006      .       AA       OLD        1
```